# Create a Mock for Stripe or use a Stub on Stripe object?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, mocha.js, stripe-payments, sinon

I'm writing tests for my `Backbone` app which uses `Stripe`. I am using `mocha-phantomjs` to run the tests. In my `index.html` file I ha `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/" type="text/javascript"></script>` to get the code for `Stripe`. 
However when I run the tests, I get the error:
`ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Stripe`, which makes sense, because I'm not running the command for the tests with a ssl certificate.

I got it working by creating a local `js` file and copied `stripe's` minified code into it, thus overriding the need of a ssl certificate and my tests passed.

However my question is if this is best practice?

Should I rather create a `sinon` mock object of `Stripe` and use that instead or would it make more sense to stub the `Stripe` object as to prevent any calls being made to the `Stripe` API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best thing to keep in mind here is separation of concerns.

Stripe is a 3rd party service and so I don't think it would be the wisest choice to use such a service in unit tests.

These are unit tests - presumably for your backbone controllers; and so the tests should strictly only be testing the controller code.

Therefore, I would mock the necessary object and methods that you require for your controller. Also this way, your unit test dependancies are cleaner.

Comment: @hyprstack yes, the mock is the best approach... especially since it will prevent the real Stripe.js from making any calls to the Stripe API.

Comment: Hi Tony. I created a mock with sinon by doing `stripeMock = sinon.mock(Stripe);` and assigning `var Stripe = {method: function () {} };`
However when I run the tests, it still complains that it cannot find `variable Stripe`. Would I need to create the object if this does not exist in the code I am testing?

Comment: @hyprstack hey, yes exactly - it should be OK if you define the variable with/without object.

Comment: so at the beginning of the test I would do `var Stripe;` then assign the mock appropriately further down.

Comment: Tony, thanks for the answer. I did as you suggested, however it still complains it cannot find the `variable Stripe`, and points to the actual `js` file I am trying to test, not the test file itself. Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: Hard to tell without more code and i'm not very familiar with backbone. Seems that you need to declare that you want `Stripe` to use *your* mock rather than the actual js file. In jasmine tests for Angular, you would inject some `$provider`'s - eg http service, modal service, stripe service. This tells the tests to inject these *before* any tests are run. I guess this kind of thing isn't happening in your test/s?

Comment: Stripe has changed the way it allows you to require it. Before you could save its minified version in a js file in your directory. Now however it requires you to get the code through the url, as I mentioned in my question. As for injecting the necessary code before any of my tests are run, I was under the impression that was what I was doing, by setting the mock in the `beforeEach/before` function of my tests. I'm using `mocha`, `chai` and `sinon` with `phantom` as my test stack. Perhaps I need to create the mock in a script tag in my `test.html` file instead of my test js file?

Comment: So that worked, setting the object in a script tag in my `test.html` file. It allows me to mock the object now.